# Tracking opened files per user onwindows server

Tags: windows, file, wmi

how can I check/track the specific file name and location of the files opened by each user (machine name) on the server. Because many times users leave files opened when other users cannot then access it? Is there anyway to track this using WMI. I want to do it programatically using any language. Is there anyway to correlate the `net session` and `net files` commands?

Answer (score 1):

The following will check the current system for any open files and output results to a CSV file:

```
wmic /output:"C:\Temp\wmic_CIM_LogicalFile.csv" /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path CIM_LogicalFile where InUseCount>'0' get /all /format:csv
```

Or remotely check for open files:

```
wmic /node:<server_ip> /output:"C:\Temp\wmic_CIM_LogicalFile.csv" /namespace:\\root\cimv2 path CIM_LogicalFile where InUseCount>'0' get /all /format:csv

Note: May require '/implevel:impersonate' &/or '/authlevel:pktPrivacy'.
```

Refer to the CIM_LogicalFile class online here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387893(v=vs.85).aspx